# Prove that the direct sum of the subspaces is mapped by isomorphism in the direct sum of the pictures of these subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

If $S$ and $T$ are subspaces of space $V$ and if is $S+T$ direct sum of subspaces $S$ and $T$, I know that is $S\cap T=\{0\}$. Also I know,from $\dim(S)+\dim(T)-\dim(S∩T)=\dim(S+T)$, that is $\dim(S)+\dim(T)=\dim(S+T)$. Also from theorem, I know that every vector from direct sum of two subspaces can represent on only one way.Can this facts help mi to solve this problem or I should think different?

Comment: Is the claim that if $\alpha: V \to W $ is an isomorphism and $V = S + T$, then $W = \alpha(S) + \alpha(T)$?

Comment: Yes,that is. @DanielLittlewood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *isomorphism* says it all. If $\phi:\>V\to W$ is an isomorphism then the complete linear structure of $V$, incl. dimensions of subspaces  etc., is losslessly copied to $W$, resp., already present there. There is nothing to prove here.